# Having trouble with react native build - com.android.build.OutputFile/com.android.tools.build

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I've been trying to build a react native app, but seem to run into endless problems so far with gradle.

Been trying to run ./gradlew clean

However, kept recieving errors.

After long troubleshooting the issue, with many fixes suggested online i was able to recieve this message showing that i'm having trouble getting it reach the repository, due to what appears to be weird variable addition.

So, i saw a suggestion online that allowed to use a copy stored locally in the project folder. So in the root folder, i created a folder named libs and added the .jar file for the gradle version i am using "8.0"
commented out the respository and entered this in code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v32Iw.png)

however, when i did this and ran ./gradlew app:dependencies  --warning-mode=all                                                         i began recieving something akin to the original error.

> Configure project :
> The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. JFrog announced JCenter's sunset in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation
> at build_gyfwbl6w1g68k9bgj77r114h$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\quail\Coding\JoeClient\android\build.gradle:47)
> (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
> at build_gyfwbl6w1g68k9bgj77r114h$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\quail\Coding\JoeClient\android\build.gradle:34)
> (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users****\Coding****\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.build.OutputFile'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I am at a loss with this issue, and know not what to do to resolve it. I am new to react native, and this is the first app i've attempted to build.